# Php remote CLI debug only works if file is mapped in path mapping (phpstorm)

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

The topic pretty much describes it all.
If i dont have file mapped in phpstorm's path mapping the xdebug wont break in it at all.
It only breaks at the first line.

Is there any way to configure phpstorm and xdebug on remote server with CLI scripts without mapping each file in phpstrom? There are lots of files to be mapped.

Comment: You do not have to map every file -- map parent folder and all subfolders will inherit the mappings

Comment: If you HAVE to map every single file .. then there is some misconfiguration/bug somewhere.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks, i'll try to reconfigure it all.

Comment: By the way: how did you configure remote interpreter ... or how do you debug this remote file in first place. Because if you do CLI debug, then maybe you are using a bit wrong Remote Interpreter configuration method ...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Had some 2 mapings on deeper files.

Solution: deleted those 2 mappings for files (without that it didn't work), added mapping for top folder.